# Edge colorability of small d/k graphs - among the largest known graphs for the undirected degree diameter problem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

What is known about the edge colorability of the graphs residing in the small $d/k$ section in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_the_largest_known_graphs_of_a_given_diameter_and_maximal_degree) table (upper left corner) ?

For example, what is the [chromatic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) of the $d=4$, $k=4$ graph with $41$ vertices in that table found by James Allwright? Is it $4$ or $5$ ?

Is there any research on this topic ?

Could you point to relevant papers on this topic ?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the 41-vertex d=4 k=3 graph by James Allwright and found that it has a four clique in its line graph. 
I also checked the linegraph with [this](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joe/Coloring/Colorsrc/smallk.html) program  but after a day of computing it did not find a 4 coloring.

After reading [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1161v1.pdf) paper I learned that this problem (whether the James graph is 4 or 5 edge colorable) can be nowadays solved exactly in a few hours on moder desktop machine having a few GFLOPs. There is an O(1.82^n) [algorithm](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00224-012-9410-7) to do that, as it is referenced in the paper.

After reading some more, I "discovered" that it is [known](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Frederic.Havet/Cours/coloration.pdf&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjVncieys7HAhWhSXIKHTncBEc&usg=AFQjCNEbpw6VYKfKLN_4NbqJmkqD6_EE5g&sig2=SAA45MNJvIKcExEFmn4J_Q) that every regular odd order graph is class two. So the James graph is class two as well.

I checked the linegraph of Exoo's 72 graph with [smallk](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joe/Coloring/Colorsrc/smallk.html) as well and it could be five colored.

Similarly, d5k2n24's line graph can be 5 colored as well, using the smallk program, it takes a few miliseconds.

As a comparison, for the line graph of the Hoffman Singleton graph the smallk program did not find a 7 coloring after a few minutes of computing even though such 7 coloring is known to exist.

Also, Exoo's n=98 d=4 k=4 graph can be 4 edge colored, according to a few milliseconds of computation using the smallk program on the line-graph of Exoo's n=98 d=4 k=4 graph.

I found a 3 coloring using the smallk program on the line graph of d3k3n20 as well after a few milliseconds of computation.

So to summarise the story (ci=chromatic index) :

```
d=3 k=2 n=10 ci=4, class 2
d=3 k=3 n=20 ci=3, class 1
d=4 k=2 n=15 ci=5  class 2
d=4 k=4 n=41 ci=5  class 2
d=4 k=4 n=98 ci=4, class 1
d=5 k=2 n=24 ci=5, class 1
d=5 k=3 n=72 ci=5, class 1
d=7 k=2 n=50 ci=7, class 1
```